# Trying to implement CSRF for a chrome extension with an ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, csrf

I am trying to create a simple chrome extension that creates a user in a mongoDB database using an express server. I am making an ajax request to the server, but I am unable to set the CSRF value! I keep getting a 403 forbidden error.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Budget Manager",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Tracking your spending",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon128.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "16": "icon16.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "notifications",
        "contextMenus",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Here is my popup.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Budget Manager</title>
    <!-- I added these later on -->
    <!-- <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/> --> 
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="create">
    <input type="submit" id="createUser" name="createMe">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my popup.js file:

```
$(function() {
    // var token = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    // $.ajaxSetup({
 //     beforeSend: function() {
 //         'X-CSRF-Token': token
 //     }
    // });

    $("#createUser").click(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).find("#createUser").val();
        var csrf = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/createUser",
            data: {id:id, _csrf:csrf },
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done(function(err,json) {
            if (err) {console.log(err);}
            console.log("success");
            console.log(json);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the app.js file with the route defined:

```
.
.
.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
.
.
.
const extensionController = require('./controllers/extension');
app.post('/createUser', extensionController.createExtensionUser);
```

Here is the express method in the controller file:

```
exports.createExtensionUser = (req, res) => {

  const user = new Extension({
    name: req.body.name
  });

  Extension.findOne({ name: req.body.name }, (err) => {
    if (err) { req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Couldnt find that user :(!'}); }
    user.save((err,user) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
      res.json(user);
    });
  });
};
```

I saw a bunch of stack overflow links that told me to set a permission of http://*/* and that it would work then! However that didn't work out for me! Then I saw a few more posts where they tried to set the CSRF headers beforehand, and tried that out below as well (it's commented out). I also tried to give a meta tag to popup.html (another StackOverflow post) and get the CSRF value from that.

So I want to know if this is the way to go about submitting a post request through the chrome extension or am I going about it totally wrong?

Comment: Right-click the popup, then Inspect to open devtools and see if there are errors in the console, check the request and response in the network panel, debug the code.

Comment: POST 403 forbidden error comes, haven't checked the network panel! What am I looking for over there?